# How to stop gulp serve / workbench?

Tags: 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts, gulp, workbench

I just started my first SPFx project on SharePoint 2016.

After I key in `gulp serve` the workbench prompt up.

My question is, how to exit the workbench?

In my DOS prompt it seems gulp is still listening and not allow me typing any command.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl +c should stop it as per the documentation

Comment: Would you give me the documentation too? I came over some troubleshooting saying existing gulp webserver dominate a port number cause other gulp not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Node JS command prompt for running commands related to SharePoint Framework.

And to stop the execution:

> Close both the local and hosted workbench and stop the local web server by pressing `CTRL+C` in the command prompt.

**Source**: [Testing with the local and hosted SharePoint Workbench](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-training-spfx-web-parts/tree/master/Demos/02-testing)

You can follow above article for testing of your web parts.

Comment: Have you tried this? Does this answer helped you in any way?